# Why Multidimensional arrays with zero as second or higher dimensions are valid in java despite they are impractical to have?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, declaration, indices

Following are valid array declarations in Java. What is the significance of having such arrays. If we look at the comments below, it doesn't even make sense, then why it is valid in Java and doesn't give any compilation error or throw a run-time exception.

```
int[][][] num = new int[3][0][5];    //3 2D matrix with 0 rows and 5 columns each
int[][] x = new int[0][4];  //0 rows and 4 columns
int[][][] y = new int[0][0][4];   //0 2D matrices each containing 0 rows and 4 columns
```

Comment: why should something that is syntactically valid give an error? in a free world you are allowed to do stupid things as long no one gets hurt...

Comment: @MarioJ.G. array[0] = 1; would throw indexOutOfBounds exception if array length is zero.

Comment: @AshishKGupta you're right, bad mistake of me.